# Best guess of the asymptotic value of a finite sequence of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-optimization

Consider an infinite sequence:
$$S_\infty := (a_1,a_2,\cdots).$$
Further, suppose that the $a_i$ are all finite and the limit $a_\infty := \lim_{i \to \infty} a_i$ is well-defined and $a_\infty$ is finite.
Besides the information above, the $a_i$ are not a priori known.

Suppose now you are being given only the first $n$ numbers of this sequence:
$$S_n = (a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$$

is there a mathematical way to have a "best guess" as to what value $a_\infty$ is?
For example, if I were to give you the following set of points, plotted in Mathematica:

[image]

I would assume most people would (correctly) guess $a_\infty=1$ (the plot is obtained by plotting $1+\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$). Is there a way to make this precise?

---

In response to @Schach21 comment, I thought about how to make mathematically precise the idea that the sequence does not do anything "crazy". Specifically, the $a_i$ in a way hold information as to what $a_\infty$ can be. The best I could come up with is the following:

In addition, you are told that there exists a set of weights $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $w_i \neq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$, such that the following holds:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_i = a_\infty.$$
In other words, a well chosen weighted average of the terms in $S_n$ will coincide with $a_\infty$.

Comment: Someone with more knowledge can confirm that, but with the conditions you currently have you can't say anything. Deeper down the sequence the $a$'s can do anything, as long as they don't grow infinitely, and that means anything. For example, for the sequence you shared, the values could suddenly jump to 2; there is nothing preventing.

Comment: @Schach21 Thanks you. I added a comment to address this.

Comment: The `answer' to this sort of thing (similar also to your other question) is explained in chapter 8 of Bender and Orszag: *Advanced mathematical methods*

Comment: Is $n$ fixed throughout? In your last paragraph, do you mean that there is a single finite sequence $w_1,\dots,w_n$, or a single infinite sequence $w_1,w_2,\dots$, or a different finite sequence for every $n$? If there's just a single finite sequence for that $n$, then all the weighted sum tells you is that $\min\{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \le a_\infty \le \max\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$.

Comment: A colleague of mine always suggests looking at sequential empirical data $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ by plotting the points $(\frac1k,a_k)$ (instead of $(k,a_k)$) to get a better view of the trend. In that light, perhaps one could estimate $a_\infty$ by finding the $y$-intercept of the line of best fit to the points $(\frac11,a_1),\dots,(\frac1n,a_n)$?

Comment: I think the average of the given points is about the best a neutral algorithm can do. If we were to analyze a Fourier transform of the sequence, assume it approximates the Fourier transform of the original sampled function, and the Fourier transform of the sampled function is approximately zero above the Nyquist frequency, that would end up just using exactly the average of the inputs to estimate the limit at infinity.

Comment: @GregMartin a different finite sequence for every n.

Comment: @aschepler See, that is what I thought at first. On the other hand, intuitively, one would think that the larger the $n$, the more weight the corresponding $a_n$ should have. As an extreme example, modifying the problem a bit, if I give you only $a_0$ and $a_{1000}$, surely one would effectively take $a_{1000}$ as our guess for $a_\infty$, instead of averaging $a_0$ and $a_{1000}$.

Comment: Presumably you mean $n\ge2$ then, since otherwise $a_\infty=a_1$. Still, all that infinite sequence of weighted sums tells us is that $a_\infty$ is between $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: The best-fit comment I made does have the property of weighting later $a_k$ more than earlier $a_k$. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is
exponential weighting.

If $0 < c \lt 1$ then

$\begin{array}\\
A_n
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kc^{n-k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n c^{n-k}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kc^{n-k}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c^{k}}\\
&=\dfrac{(1-c)\sum_{k=1}^n a_kc^{n-k}}{1-c^n}\\
\end{array}
$

A nice property of this
is that it is
computationally efficient:
$A_{n+1}$
can be gotten from
$A_n$ simply.

Let
$B_n
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kc^{-k}
$
so
$A_n
=\dfrac{(1-c)c^nB_n}{1-c^n}
=\dfrac{(1-c)B_n}{c^{-n}-1}
$
or
$B_n
=A_n\dfrac{c^{-n}-1}{1-c}
$.
Then
$B_{n+1}
=B_n+a_{n+1}c^{-n-1}
$
so

$A_{n+1}\dfrac{c^{-n-1}-1}{1-c}
=A_n\dfrac{c^{-n}-1}{1-c}+a_{n+1}c^{-n-1}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
A_{n+1}
&=A_n\dfrac{c^{-n}-1}{1-c}\dfrac{1-c}{c^{-n-1}-1}+a_{n+1}c^{-n-1}\dfrac{1-c}{c^{-n-1}-1}\\
&=A_n\dfrac{c^{-n}-1}{c^{-n-1}-1}+a_{n+1}c^{-n-1}\dfrac{1-c}{c^{-n-1}-1}\\
&=A_n\dfrac{c-c^{n+1}}{1-c^{n+1}}+a_{n+1}\dfrac{1-c}{1-c^{n+1}}\\
&=(1-b_{n+1})A_n+b_{n+1}a_{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

where
$b_{n+1}
=\dfrac{1-c}{1-c^{n+1}}
$.

We can get
$b_{n+1}$
in terms of
$b_n$,
but I don't know how useful this is,
since just getting
$c^{n+1}
=c\cdot c^n$
seems good enough.
Anyway, here it is.

Since
$1-c^n
=\dfrac{1-c}{b_n}
$,
$c^n
=1-\dfrac{1-c}{b_n}
$
so
$c^{n+1}
=c-\dfrac{c(1-c)}{b_n}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
b_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{1-c}{1-c^{n+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-c}{1-c-\dfrac{c(1-c)}{b_n}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-c}{1-\dfrac{c}{b_n}}\\
&=\dfrac{b_n(1-c)}{b_n-c}\\
\end{array}
$